# Java List<> метод из другого вопроса, как запустить

Tags: java, list

Я в упор не могу понять как передать данному методу параметр. Компилятор говорит:

> type does not take parameters.

Версия Java 9.0.4

```
public class Program
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //pls help, how can i run it?
}

public static List<Integer> din(int number) {
    String n = Integer.toString(number) ;
    char[] charArray = n.toCharArray();
    List<Integer> cia = new ArrayList<Integer> () ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<charArray.length;i++) 
    {
    int c = Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i])} ;
    cia.add(c);
    System.out.println(cia[i]);
}
return cia ;
}
```

Comment: Вы код и скобки всегда так выравниваете или это случайность?

Comment: В приведенном коде несколько ошибок компиляции, но сообщения `type does not take parameters`. Приведите [минимальный код, который демонстрирует проблему,](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) убедитесь что в нем нет других ошибок и укажите строку, на которой возникает проблема.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static List<Integer> din(int number) {
        String n = Integer.toString(number) ;
        char[] charArray = n.toCharArray();
        List<Integer> cia = new ArrayList<Integer> () ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<charArray.length;i++) {
            int c = Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
            cia.add(c);
            System.out.println(cia.get(i));
        }
        return cia ;
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        din(310);  // или любое другое целое число типа int
}
```

Ошибка `type List does not take parameters` может быть из-за того, что вместо  `java.util.List` вы импортировали `java.awt.List`, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так уже пробовал, и щас вот ещё раз попробовал. Говорит type List does not take parameters. По поводу оформления, извиняюсь, писал с телефона, на компе на работе нет интернетов.

Comment: @СтасSpindle, а вы импортировали именно  java.util.List ?

Comment: @СтасSpindle, или, может, случайно java.awt.List ?

Comment: https://vk.com/photo1622528_456239868 вот так это выглядит. Я импортировал util. Второй день шткдирую интернет чтобы понять как заставить это работать, на английском оверфлоуве тема не правильного импорта уже раскрыта.

Answer (score 0):

Автобоксинг не работает с массивами. Вы использует как обертки так и примитивы в методе. Попробуйте перейти на примитивы или вручную конвертировать обертки.
https://habr.com/post/329498/

Comment: Спасибо изучу! А может тогда с ходу посоветуете хорошую литературу по Яве уровня чуть выше новичка?

Comment: @Ya Si, у автора вопроса cia - это не массив, а список...